# Dutch text to be translated

Tags: translation-request

This is a physics text but in Physics Stack Exchange there is no translation request tag. Please let me know of another site if you cannot help me with this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Although there is no translation-request tag, I still suspect that this post is better suited for the physics SE site